# Wordpress load js inside template

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am looking for a way to init my js when needed. i have simple builder based on AcvencedCustomFields and there i have MAP module and i need to load JS only when map module is used so i have this function in `functions.php`

```
function my_acf_map(){
    wp_enqueue_script('acf-map', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/acf-map.js');    
    wp_enqueue_script('googleapis', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false');
}
```

and inside map template i added this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_acf_map');
do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_acf_map');
```

so every time when map module is used this two lines of code execute. All is working well but i dont know is this is propper method? what if i have 10x times of map module on page so these lines will execute 10x times?? is this making any conflict?? or breaking some rules?

Comment: see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque

Comment: so my way is correct?

Comment: yes it will enqueue only once when your template load. if you use both code in functions.php it will load everywhere. whenever you need or not.